# How does "vadis" mean "you go"?

Tags: gerund

Apparently in the Acts of Peter, it reads at one point, "Domine, quo vadis?" Meaning, "Lord, where are you going?".

However, I do not understand this form, *vadis*. The forms I know are:

```
vadas   - you go
vadabis - you will go
```

As far as I know, the idea of "Where are you going?" would be:

```
Quo ad vadandum es?
```

Where is the translator getting "vadis"?

Comment: Where are you getting these forms *vadas, vadabis*?

Comment: Also, why _vadandum es_? Surely a finite verb works just fine without periphrasis?

Comment: @TKR Looks like I was looking at the wrong word. I was reading the paradigm for vado, vadare to wade or ford a river.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb is *vādō, vādere*, not **vādō, vādāre*. Hence the well-known imperative singular *vāde*.